# Options for synchronizing Palm Desktop calendars

Tags: sync, calendar, palm

My wife and I each have Palm Centro phones and very full calendars. We've been using Palm products for years and are happy with them and are not looking to switch (and don't have the budget for it even if we wanted to).

What is a viable way we can synchronize our calendars?

Back when we had Palm Z22s we used [AirSet](http://www.airset.com/). It worked great in synchronizing our desktop calendars. Unfortunately, their sync software does not support Palm Desktop v6 and there is nothing in the pipeline to support it. (The third party vendor is apparently not interested in updating for the newer Palm desktop.)

I would love to be able to get back to having each other's appointments appear on the other's calendar. What can we do?

Some limitations:

- A data plan is not an option (so this precludes over-the-air synchronization options)
- No Microsoft Outlook

**Edit**: Syncing my Palm to my Palm Desktop is not the issue. Being able to sync, in some way, the Palm calendar databases of my wife's and my calendars is what's desired.

Comment: Please confirm, you need to see your wife's calendar on your Palm.
Do the calendars need to be maintained separately, or could they be combined into one calendar that you both sync to?

Comment: Calendars need to be separately maintained. She doesn't need to know about the thousand meetings I have at work every day, for instance, nor do I need to see the particulars of her study groups. Mostly it's to ensure we both no what events the children have and any commitments either of us have for evenings/weekends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, I never did find a solution to this issue.

That's okay, because we moved all of our data to Google Calendar and have Android phones.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [DualDate](http://mytreo.net/downloads/palm-dualdate,422.html) will help you.

> DualDate is a new program from Palm
>   that is an enhanced version of the
>   standard Date Book.
>
> Unlike the original Date Book,
>   DualDate lets you share your calendar
>   with family, friends and colleagues.
>   You can therefore receive somebody
>   else's calendar too.
>
> Calendars are shared simply by beaming
>   DualDate to another user, and this can
>   include private events if you wish.
>   Privacy is maintained but the
>   dates/times that they occur are
>   included.
>
> When you receive another user's
>   calendar DualDate automatically
>   converts to a dual view mode, which
>   allows you to see both sets of entries
>   simultaneously.
>
> Received calendars can be viewed, but
>   not altered. Any changes to either
>   calendar can be updated on the other
>   device simply by beaming the calendar
>   again.

It's not as easy as AirSet looks to be. But I think it's the most you can get near this functionality.

BTW I would remember you that you can change the default app launched by a button at `Prefs > Personal > Buttons` (as translated from pt`_`BR localization of my Tungsten E2 by *me*). So, you can change your "`Cal button`" for opening DualDate instead of DateBook.

Comment: Looks intriguing. I'll check it out.

Comment: I used to use Dual Date and it worked great.  Unfortunately the docs show that it is only for Palm OS Palm OS® 3.5, 4.0, or 4.1.  The Centros runs Palm OS 5.4.9.

http://www.palm.com/us/support/handbooks/dualdate_ug.pdf

Comment: But you know, it's a old-old-old program. You can't download it by Palm's site anymore! Who knows if it works for the most recent PalmOS? I have a Tungsten E2, but there's no point on testing since I don't have another palm for beaming testing. xD

Comment: It was promising, but it totally hosed my wife's Centro.

Comment: >.<  
Keep using PalmOS is almost an error, those times.
I own a Tungsten E2, and I feel totally abandoned. +1 'cos I live in Brazil: People don't have ANY idea about when will Palm Pre come to this country.
I think you should sit down at night and sync manually your calendars. All I know about PalmOS is: you won't get the app you want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're going to be able to combine the two calendars in the local computer, without going through some external service.  (See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419441/need-palm-desktop-datebook-dat-file-format) on StackOverlow.)  I think you're going to have to find a way to sync either the phones or the desktop calendars to an external calendar to combine them.

I've been using the paid version of [GooSync](http://goosync.zendesk.com/forums/30163/entries/20464) for the last couple of years to sync my phone calendar to Google Calendar.  I can see my partner's separate calendar on-line.  I copy the critical or potentially conflicting appointments to my calendar, which are then synced back to my phone through GooSync.  Another option would be for us to share one on-line calendar.

Two other similar services to Google Calendar are [ScheduleWorld](http://wiki.scheduleworld.com/wiki/How_Do_I_Share_Calendars) and [Funambol](https://www.forge.funambol.org/download/documentation.html).  A few years ago, I played with ScheduleWorld, and eventually settled on Goosync.

Good luck.  When you find a solution that works for you, please post it.

Comment: Well, yes, I was expecting to need to use an external service. I didn't think GooSync was going to be an option because I'm precluded from syncing from the phone; I need to use the desktop. I'll take another look at GooSync.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you could synchronize both with the same google calendar account or one of the other internet based calendars.

Comment: That would be nice, but how? There is no app to sync my Palm Desktop to Google Calendar. That's what I **used** to do with AirSet. Hence my question here.

Comment: There are a few out there that claim to do it like goosync I just googled for palm google synchronizatin and lots of stuff popped up.

Comment: Just read your comment on the previous answer I'm fairly sure it works from the desktop since it works with the Tx which doesn't have a phone data connection.